# c# Webapi and model binding with fluentvalidation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

how do I get asp.net webapi to look at the route data and body to bind to a complex object?

Using the following route "api/products/{productid}/manufacturers/{manufacturerId}" I need the productId and manufacturerId to bind to a model, so my controller method is as

```
public IHttpActionResult Create(CreateProductManufacturerModel
                createProductManufacturerModel)
```

and my model is

```
 public class CreateProductManufacturerModel
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
        public string ManufacturerCode { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

I know I could change my method to be as below, but I am using fluentvalidation to validate the whole createproductmanufacturermodel, this is done automatically (see- http://www.justinsaraceno.com/2014/07/fluentvalidation-with-webapi2/). So the productId and manufacturerId would not be validated correctly as the are set as zero.

```
   public IHttpActionResult Create(int productId, int manufacturerId, CreateProductManufacturerModel
                createProductManufacturerModel)
```

I've have tried a modelbinder but it then does not fire the fluentvalidation automatically. Not too sure if this matters, but the body being posted is in a json format.

Thanks in advance.

Paul

Comment: Why cant you  add productId and manufacturerId in `createproductmanufacturermodel`  with  other values in json data ?

Comment: you could, but that makes me feel dirty, as the data is supplied twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Inherit `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute`.
2. Override `OnActionExecuting()`
3. Extract routing data using `actionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values`
4. Extract model using `actionContext.ActionArguments`
5. Validate and assign routing data to model properties
6. Decorate your action with the new attribute you created.

If this is a less specific use case, you can use reflection to assign routing data to model properties according to param names.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your action signature to be:

```
public IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody]CreateProductManufacturerModel
            createProductManufacturerModel){}
```

and then validate the 2 values you need: createProductManufacturerModel.ProductId  and createProductManufacturerModel.ManufacturerId ?

Comment: I'm currently using the method with the productId, manufacturerId and createProductManufacturerModel that I mentioned. As I currently have fluentvalidation firing the validation automatically. I would have two set of validations :(